# multiple python class inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to understand python's class inheritance methods and I have some troubles figuring out how to do the following:

How can I inherit a method from a class **conditional** on the child's input?

I have tried the following code below without much success.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def something(self):
        print("Function %s" % self.path)   


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.c = 'something'

    def something(self):
        print('%s function with %s' % (self.path, self.c))


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, path):
        # super(C, self).__init__(path)

        if path=='A':
            A.__init__(self, path)
        if path=='B':
            B.__init__(self, path)
        print('class: %s' % self.path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    C('A')
    out = C('B')
    out.something()
```

I get the following output:

```
class: A
class: B
Function B
```

While I would like to see:

```
class: A
class: B
B function with something
```

I guess the reason why `A.something()` is used (instead of `B.something()`) has to do with the python's MRO.

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not just make two separate classes, `CA` and `CB`, that inherit from either base, then pick from those classes when creating an instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `__init__` on either parent class does not change the inheritance structure of your classes, no. You are only changing what initialiser method is run in addition to `C.__init__` when an instance is created. `C` inherits from both `A` and `B`, and all methods of `B` are shadowed by those on `A` due to the order of inheritance.

If you need to alter class inheritance based on a value in the constructor, create **two separate classes**, with different structures. Then provide a different callable as the API to create an instance:

```
class CA(A):
    # just inherit __init__, no need to override

class CB(B):
    # just inherit __init__, no need to override

def C(path):
    # create an instance of a class based on the value of path
    class_map = {'A': CA, 'B': CB}
    return class_map[path](path)
```

The user of your API still has name `C()` to call; `C('A')` produces an instance of a different class from `C('B')`, but they both implement the same interface so this doesn't matter to the caller.

If you *have* to have a common 'C' class to use in `isinstance()` or `issubclass()` tests, you could mix one in, and use the [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) to override what subclass is returned:

```
class C:
    def __new__(cls, path):
        if cls is not C:
            # for inherited classes, not C itself
            return super().__new__(cls)
        class_map = {'A': CA, 'B': CB}
        cls = class_map[path]
        # this is a subclass of C, so __init__ will be called on it
        return cls.__new__(cls, path)

class CA(C, A):
    # just inherit __init__, no need to override
    pass

class CB(C, B):
    # just inherit __init__, no need to override
    pass
```

`__new__` is called to construct the new instance object; if the `__new__` method returns an instance of the class (or a subclass thereof) then `__init__` will automatically be called on that new instance object. This is why `C.__new__()` returns the result of `CA.__new__()` or `CB.__new__()`; `__init__` is going to be called for you.

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> C('A').something()
Function A
>>> C('B').something()
B function with something
>>> isinstance(C('A'), C)
True
>>> isinstance(C('B'), C)
True
>>> isinstance(C('A'), A)
True
>>> isinstance(C('A'), B)
False
```

If neither of these options are workable for your specific usecase, you'd have to add more routing in a new `somemethod()` implementation on `C`, which then calls either `A.something(self)` or `B.something(self)` based on `self.path`. This becomes cumbersome really quickly when you have to do this for *every single method*, but a decorator could help there:

```
from functools import wraps

def pathrouted(f):
    @wraps
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # call the wrapped version first, ignore return value, in case this
        # sets self.path or has other side effects
        f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # then pick the class from the MRO as named by path, and call the
        # original version
        cls = next(c for c in type(self).__mro__ if c.__name__ == self.path)
        return getattr(cls, f.__name__)(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

then use that on empty methods on your class:

```
class C(A, B):
    @pathrouted
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        # either A.__init__ or B.__init__ will be called next

    @pathrouted
    def something(self):
        pass  # doesn't matter, A.something or B.something is called too
```

This is, however, becoming very unpythonic and ugly.

Answer (score 2):

While Martijn's answer is (as usual) close to perfect, I'd just like to point out that from a design POV, inheritance is the wrong tool here.

Remember that implementation inheritance is actually a static and somehow restricted kind of composition/delegation, so as soon as you want something more dynamic the proper design is to eschew inheritance and go for full composition/delegation, canonical examples being the State and the Strategy patterns. Applied to your example, this might look something like:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, strategy):
        self.strategy = strategy

    def something(self):
        return self.strategy.something(self)

class AStrategy(object):
    def something(self, owner):
        print("Function A")

class BStrategy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = "something"

    def something(self, owner):
        print("B function with %s" % self.c)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = C(AStrategy())
    a.something()
    b = C(BStrategy())
    b.something()
```

Then if you need to allow the user to specify the strategy by name (as string), you can add the factory pattern to the solution

```
STRATEGIES = {
    "A": AStrategy,
    "B": BStrategy, 
    }

def cfactory(strategy_name):
  try:
      strategy_class = STRATEGIES[strategy_name]
  except KeyError:
      raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid strategy" % strategy_name)
  return C(strategy_class())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = cfactory("A")
    a.something()
    b = cfactory("B")
    b.something()
```

Comment: Much easier to follow than using multiple inheritence

Answer (score 0):

Martijn's answer explained how to choose an object inheriting from one of two classes. Python also allows to easily forward a method to a different class:

```
>>> class C:
    parents = { 'A': A, 'B': B }
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.parent = C.parents[path]
        self.parent.__init__(self, path)                 # forward object initialization
    def something(self):
        self.parent.something(self)                      # forward something method


>>> ca = C('A')
>>> cb = C('B')
>>> ca.something()
Function A
>>> cb.something()
B function with something
>>> ca.path
'A'
>>> cb.path
'B'
>>> cb.c
'something'
>>> ca.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    ca.c
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'c'
>>>
```

But here class C does not inherit from A or B:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>)
```

---

Below is my original solution using *monkey patching*:

```
>>> class C:
    parents = { 'A': A, 'B': B }
    def __init__(self, path):
        parent = C.parents[path]
        parent.__init__(self, path)                      # forward object initialization
        self.something = lambda : parent.something(self) # "borrow" something method
```

it avoids the `parent` attribute in C class, but is less readable...

Comment: While monkeypatching is a handy workaround sometimes, I would definitly not advise using it as part of a proper design. What you're doing here is mostly a non standard and rather brittle implemention of the strategy pattern, so better to go for a more canonical (and robust) strategy implementation.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: I must admit that monkey patching is rather rough... This one now dynamically forwards a method to a different class