# How to dynamically inherit at initialization time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, metaclass

I have the following class structure:

```
class Base:
  def z(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

class A(Base):
  def z(self):
    self._x()
    return self._z()

  def _x(self):
    # do stuff

  def _a(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()

class B(Base)
  def z(self):
    self._x()
    return self._z()

  def _x(self):
    # do stuff

  def _z(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()


class C(A):
  def _z(self):
    print(5)

class D(B):
  def _z(self):
    print(5)
```

The implementation of `C(A)` and `D(B)` is exactly the same and does not really care which class it inherits from. The conceptual difference is only in `A` and `B` (and these need to be kept as separate classes). Instead of writing separate definitions for `C` and `D`, I want to be able to dynamically inherit from `A` or `B` based on an argument provided at time of creating an **instance** of `C`/`D` (eventually `C` and `D` must be the same name).

It seems that metaclasses might work, but I am not sure how to pass an `__init__` argument to the metaclass `__new__` (and whether this will actually work). I would really prefer a solution which resolves the problem inside the class.

Comment: This question looks close to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50036737/3545273), if not a true duplicate...

Comment: Why do you need that? I have the feeling there might be better ways.

Comment: In a nutshell, I have classes (`C` and `D` above) which should either run threads in parallel (`A`) or sequentially (`B`). The overall resulting behavior is the same with either `A` or `B`, with slight difference in performance and accuracy. The behavior of all `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `Base` is extremely similar and the inheritance structure needs to be as given, so composition is not really suitable. What other ways would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using composition instead of inheritance? It seems like it is much more suitable for this use case. See the bottom of the answer for details.

Anyway,

- `class C(A): .........  class C(B): .....` is not even valid, and will result with only `class C(B)` getting defined.
- I'm not sure a metaclass will be able to help you here. I believe the best way would be to use `type` but I'd love to be corrected.

A solution using `type` (and probably misusing `locals()` but that's not the point here)

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Inherited from A')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Inherited from B')

class_to_inherit = input()  # 'A' or 'B"

C = type('C', (locals()[class_to_inherit],), {})

C()

'A' or 'B'
>> A
Inherited from A

'A' or 'B'
>> B
Inherited from B
```

**Composition**

Tracking back to the question in the beginning of my answer, you state yourself that the implementation of both "`C(A)`" and "`C(B)`" is identical and they don't actually care about `A` or `B`. It seems more correct to me to use composition. Then you can do something along the lines of:

```
class A: pass

class B: pass

class C:
    def __init__(self, obj):  # obj is either A or B instance, or A or B themselves
        self.obj = obj  # or self.obj = obj() if obj is A or B themselves

c = C(A())  #  or c = C(A)
```

In case `C` should expose the same API as `A` or `B`, `C` can overwrite `__getattr__`:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

class C:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.obj, item)

C(A()).foo()
# foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately composition is not a good solution for my specific use case because `C` is supposed to provide the same API as A. Maybe the solution using `type` with a combination of a function which determines the correct class will do the trick. I will leave it open for some more time to see if other ideas come up.

Comment: @niko " `C` is supposed to provide the same API as `A` " this can be achieved by using composition as well by overwriting `__getattr__` in `C` for example `def __getattr__(self, item): return getattr(self.obj, item)` It works, but is it a good approach? not sure. See updated answer.

Comment: Sure, but then it becomes a mess to track which members belong to `A` and which to `C`. Surely it is doable, but I feel like the solution with `type` is clearer. Also in my case, A and C should are conceptually the same thing, with A providing an implementation for abstract methods of C